# Calling Constructor doesn't create the JFrame (Swing)

Tags: java, constructor, jframe

I'm trying to Optimize my Graphical MineSweeper; what I want to do is create a JFrame which instantly starts the game, but when I call the Constructor  to generate it, it simply shows nothing more than the window :(

I'm forced to create a JFrame in which I have to click in order to create the JFrame: here's some code.

Launcher (Main method):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MineSweeper");
    Menu menu = new Menu(frame, 11, 11, 10);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu.operation());

    frame.setSize(300,100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(new JLabel("MineSweeper 0.9 by ME ;)",SwingConstants.CENTER));

    // new MineSweeper(11,11,10);   <---- not working alone
    }
}
```

MineSweeper (rest of code):

```
public class MineSweeper extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener {
    /* useless instance variables */
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel gridPanel, optionsPanel;
private int[][] gridWithNumbers;
    private JToggleButton[][] gridWithGraphics;
/* useless instance variables */

public MineSweeper(int maxRows, int maxCols, int maxMines) {
    this.maxRows = maxRows;
    this.maxCols = maxCols;
    this.maxMines = maxMines;


    gridWithNumbers = new int[maxRows][maxCols];
    gridWithGraphics = new JToggleButton[maxRows][maxCols]; 


    gridPanel = new JPanel();
    //  gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(maxRows-2,maxCols-2,1,1)); <--- nevermind this

    frame = new JFrame("MineSweeper");
    //frame.setSize( (int)(21 * maxCols) - 11 , (int)(21.5 * maxRows) + 83 );         <---  nice numbers, nevermind 
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

/* ...... */
```

Comment: if you can make the first frame visible from main, you should be able to make any frame visible.  why not move all of the `frame = new frame(minesweeper);...` code out of the minesweeper constructor, and do that setup in main, like you are with the other one?

Comment: Perhaps this article, [Minesweeper Applet](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=300), can help you see how to build one JFrame with a start button and mine buttons.